# How to Remove a Per User File Association

Tags: c#, windows, registry

Apologies in advance for another question on File Associations.  I have changed the code I use to create a file association so that it uses HKEY_CURRRENT_USER\Software\Classes.  This gets past the problem of requiring Admin rights (Thanks to David Heffernan for persisting with me on that one).

I found that continued creation of the file association does not duplicate it in the registry but changes the data.  So if I assign to a different executable it replaces the previous with the current.  However I wanted to see how to clear a file association completely.  I simply search for the entry and if it is there remove the key:

```
public static void RemoveAssociation(string extension) {
       if (!IsAssociated(extension)) return;
       var currentUser = Registry.CurrentUser;
       var softwareKey = getKey(currentUser, "Software");
       if (softwareKey != null) {
           var softwareClasses = getKey(softwareKey, "Classes");
           if (softwareClasses != null) {
               softwareClasses.DeleteSubKey(extension);
           }
       }
}
```

IsAssociated just looks for the extension key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes

This does remove the key but not all the entries in the registry.  I found an entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT as well as in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\EXTENSIONS.  (I am running Win 7 so I but I assume this will be present in XP and Vista?)

Double Clicking the extension now results in a dialog telling me that windows cannot find the associated executable (presumably because I have left the key in CLASSES_ROOT but removed the connection by deleting the key)

So how do I cleanly remove all references to the extension?

Thanks

EDIT

This is the code I am using to create the association:

```
public static void Associate(string extension, string progID, string description, string icon, string application) {
    if (extension == null) return;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(progID)) return;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(application)) return;

    var currentUser = Registry.CurrentUser;
    var softwareKey = getKey(currentUser, "Software");

    if (softwareKey != null) {
        var softwareClasses = getKey(softwareKey, "Classes");

        if (softwareClasses != null) {
            softwareClasses.CreateSubKey(extension).SetValue("", progID);

            using (var key = softwareClasses.CreateSubKey(progID)) {
                    if (description != null)
                        key.SetValue("", description);
                    if (icon != null)
                        key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", toShortPathName(icon));
                    //if (application != null)
                        key.CreateSubKey(@"Shell\Open\Command").SetValue("", toShortPathName(application) + " \"%1\"");
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You code appears to remove the file type mapping, but not the progID. Do you have full code for how you install the association?

Comment: I added it to the original question.  Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation I have read, when uninstalling you are meant to remove the progID, but leave the extension. You are doing the opposite.